# Prevent Django Pipeline from post processing certain files

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

I'm currently implementing Django Pipeline to minify my CSS/JS but I would like to stop it appending unique identifiers to certain files.

This is because I am using django-tinymce and certain popups fail due to Django Pipeline. I get the following error message:

```
"The requested URL /static/tiny_mce/plugins/table/table.htm/ was not found on this server.
```

As Django pipeline has changed table.htm to:

```
Post-processed 'tiny_mce/plugins/table/table.htm' as 'tiny_mce/plugins/table/table.88fb36057ec1.htm
```

If anyone knows how to turn this bit off on certain apps I would appreciate it as I can;t find anything in the docs.

Comment: If it helps try webassets(http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for compressing static media resources. You can define your CSS and JS files which you want to minify/compress in your templates.

Comment: Hey, sorry I realised I'm a colossal idiot :) See my answer for details.

Comment: I'm still interested in a solution that helps django pipeline ignore certain files for post processing.  Even without modifications, collectstatic with Amazon S3 and cached files is post processing the same files over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked out the issue was Apache adding a forward slash to the url, not a problem with django-pipeline.